# Windows 8 OEM Reinstalling

Tags: windows-8, installation, oem

I know this question is a repetition but I didn't find any solution of my problem from any of the previous questions. Recently I formatted my Laptop HDD and now I want to re install windows 8 I've a Windows 8 OEM license but the problem is I don't have a disc , I downloaded **en_windows_8_x64_dvd_915440** from msdn , but when I boot the windows it shows the error that the current version is not suitable with my serial key, so where I can find an OEM Windows 8 and also I've a retail windows 8 disc so if I install that windows 8 in my pc and is there any way to activate it using my OEM key

Comment: The .iso you downloaded should have worked. Did your laptop come with Windows 8 or Windows 8 Professional? Because what you downloaded was only Windows 8, so a Windows 8 Professional license, wouldn't have been accepted unless you modified the .iso to accept it.  If you have a retail license of say Windows 8, its trivial to change the license to your OEM license, provided you know what it is and its the same type of license.  You were vague in all accounts, once you clarify what versions of Windows 8, a specific answer can be provided.

Comment: Most computers/laptops have a hidden partition that allows the OS to be reinstalled. It is accessed by certain keystrokes during the boot process. Each manufacturer has their own keystoke combo to accomplish this

Comment: you may have the Windows 8 Core Single Language Edition and this Edition is not included in the MSDN ISO.

Comment: @magicandre1981 yep its Windows 8 Core Single Language Edition. is there anyway to download this

Comment: there are no official links to the Single Language Edition. Ask your OEM for a DVD.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to find an unbranded OEM install disk. Otherwise, you should contact who issued the licence to you in the first place (Laptop manufacturer most likely), as they should be able to provide the correct OEM installation disks.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking:

**The right way to do it**

1. Get the recovery discs from your system backup - *You have one of those, right?* (most OEMs have a utility installed to burn the recovery to external media to avoid this type of issue)
2. Most OEMs will sell them for a fairly cheap
3. You could see if a local repair shop would let you use theirs

**Other Possibilities**

1. If your computer is common, you might be able to get the recovery media from one (friends, family, possibly a PC shop is nice and lets you burn a copy from there) - slightly questionable.